# How to keep track of new data appended to SQL table?

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

I am currently using RSQLite and R to create a database.

I would like to append new rows of data the following table "my_table" in the database.

I would like to keep track of what data has been appended to "my_table".

I currently have the following table:

```
id|website 
1 | google.com
2 | msn.com
3 | yahoo.com
4 | youtube.com
```

If i have a new row of data to append

```
id|website 
5 | facebook.com
```

Also assuming that a primary key exists on the id column, so there cannot be any duplicates.

How can i keep track of the new data that has been appended. Do i need to include a new column with a UUID or date or something?

Comment: How are you adding data to this table/data frame?

Comment: You can add a Status field, with a default value that you identify as NEW, or you can create a trigger on the INSERT command on the table. It depends on how you handle data and what you need to do on new records. But consider that usually triggers should be avoided for this kind of check.

Comment: Depending on how detailed you want this tracking to be, you can add columns for the date the record was created, the date it was last updated (modified), even the date it was deleted (if you allow "soft" deletion).  It's entirely up to you to ensure that these dates are kept up to date, either using a trigger, or in code/ scripts.  You don't even have to keep the audit data in the same table, which comes in handy if you also want to store history, e.g. if someone changes id 3 from yahoo.com to yahoo.co.uk, and you want to know when, and what it was before the current record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get the max id from your table to increment it:

```
library(RMySQL)
max_id = dbGetQuery(my_database,"select max(id) from my_table")
```

Then you can update the id on your data:

```
new_row$id = max_id+1

# or for multiple rows
new_row$id = max_id + as.numeric(row.names(new_row))
```

then you can append to your database:

```
dbWriteTable(my_database,"my_table",new_row,append=T, row.names=FALSE)
```